# Combinatoricien vs combinatoriste

Tags: vocabulaire, anglicismes, mathématiques

Une spécialité mathématique s'appelle la [combinatoire](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatoire). Les experts de cette spécialité sont tantôt appelés *combinatoriciens*, tantôt appelés *combinatoristes*. Quelles seraient des raisons linguistiquement fondées de préférer une version à l'autre ? *Combinatoriste* n'est-il qu'un anglicisme ? Plus généralement, à quelles nuances correspondent ces deux terminaisons ?

Quelques exemples du domaine, en *-cien* : mathématique (mathématicien), logique (logicien), statistique (statisticien), informatique (informaticien), mécanique (mécanicien).

Quelques exemples du domaine, en *-iste* ou *-yste* : analyse (analyste), algèbre (algébriste), probabilités (probabiliste), équations aux dérivées partielles (édépiste, *jargon*).

Quelques exemples du domaine, autres : géométrie (géomètre), topologie (topologue).

**Post-scriptum** Dans un autre domaine que les mathématiques, *histoire* donne *historien*.

Comment: Vu que la _combinatoire_ est aussi appelée _analyse combinatoire_, j'aurais tendance à préférer _analyste combinatoire_ ou _mathématicien combinatoire_.

Comment: Oui oui, ce serait effectivement fort logique. Mais aucun des deux n'est employé par personne...

Comment: Ils sont au [coude](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22combinatoricien%22) à [coude](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22combinatoriste%22) au Google fight, et pas recensés sur Google Books. Je dirais *combinatoricien* les jours impairs et *combinatoriste* les jours pairs.

Answer (score 13):

Dans l'hypothèse où il existe des mathématiciens spécialistes de combinatoire, j'aurais plutôt tendance à les appeller *analystes combinatoires*, *spécialistes de la combinatoire* ou si je dois l'employer souvent *combinatoristes*.

Pour ce qui est des fondements linguistiques, d'après [ce tableau](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe%3aSuffixes_en_fran%C3%A7ais#i) (non sourcé), on a

> -ien : profession, habitant
>
> -iste : adepte d'une activité, adepte d'une idéologie politique

Peut-être considère-t-on que ce sont des combinatoriciens si c'est leur emploi et combinatoristes si ça les amuse.

À l'inverse, le [Dictionnaire des suffixes du français](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=suffixes%20fran%C3%A7ais&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEUQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dixel.fr%2Fpdf%2Fdictionnaire-des-suffixes.pdf&ei=F8y6TsaeB6fR4QSnzdG4CA&usg=AFQjCNEssPWiV8a-Hyml1JxnhuUvkj4JbA&cad=rja) donne pour *-ien*

> Spécialiste de, qui s'occupe de

Sans précisions pour *-iste*.

Allez savoir…

Concernant ce soupçon d'anglicisme, en revanche, comme ni l'un ni l'autre ne sont présent dans les dictionnaires de référence habituels je me suis ramené au cas de *analyste*, qui d'après le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/alg%C3%A9bristee) date du seizième siècle, donc est presque sûrement un non-anglicisme<sup>1</sup>. Les autres *-istes* en maths viennent certainement du même tonneau, ou par analogie.

---

<sup>1. laule</sup>

Comment: _copiste_ daterait du quinzième

Comment: Merci pour ces éléments. Quelques commentaires. Oui *il existe des mathématiciens spécialistes de combinatoire* donc l'emploi du mot *hypothèse* semble mal venu ici, à moins de sous-entendus qui gagneraient à être explicités. Bien que Wikipedia propose *analyse combinatoire* comme dénomination alternative du champ, *analystes combinatoires* est impossible car les combinatoriciens ne sont pas tous analystes, loin de là. *Spécialistes de la combinatoire* est une périphrase peu satisfaisante. Enfin la distinction entre emploi sérieux .../...

Comment: .../... et distraction ne correspond ni aux exemples que je donne ni à d'autres. Hummm... comme on dit en bas moldovalaque, *the plot thickens*...

Comment: @DidierPiau Le seul sous-entendu c'est que je n'ai jamais entendu parler de spécialistes de la combinatoire, donc je ne sais pas comment les autres les appellent. Et pourquoi un emploi sérieux ne pourrait pas être une disraction ? =)

Comment: Entendu. Pour votre information, [05-XX](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/msc2010.html?t=05-XX).

Comment: +1, parce que donner une réponse à la fois consistante et humoristique est tellement rare ! (-iste si ça les amuse, j'en ris encore, laule !)

Answer (score 5):

Dans la communauté, on a plutôt tendance à utiliser combinatoricien. Combinatoriste sonne un peu bizarrement mais on l'entend de temps à autre. On précise parfois de quelle combinatoire il s'agit, et rencontrons par exemple des combinatoriciens algébrique, combinatoriciens analytique, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Et pourquoi pas "combinatorien" ? (histoire/historien, voire
oratoire/oratorien). C'est d'ailleurs le mot utilisé dans le
récent avis de décès de Louis Comtet.

Comment: Parce qu'on construit les néologismes sur la règle plutôt que sur l'exception ? Et/ou que les maths s'accomodent bien de longs et pointillieux *-iciens*, depuis les pythagoriciens, peut-être ?

Comment: Parce que je n'avais JAMAIS entendu ni lu ce mot avant de parcourir dans la [Gazette](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Gazette/2011/127/smf_gazette_127_107-116.pdf) la recension du livre *Analytic combinatorics* de Flajolet et Sedgewick, recension rédigée par **J** - **P** **A** llouche.

Answer (score 2):

Le terme [*combinatoire*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/combinatoire) est un dérivé du verbe [*combiner*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/combiner) (un emprunt du bas latin *combinare (bini)* ; la [*combinaison*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/combinaison) est empruntée au bas latin *combinatio*) suffixé en [-oire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-oire) et précédé d'une consonne de liaison. Si on veut le suffixer à son tour pour créer l'agent, quelle forme de base utiliserait-on puisqu'il est « assez rare » (LBU14 167a) que ce soit le mot simple sur lequel l'opération s'effectue : le radical du verbe, du nom, voire celui de leur version latine le cas échéant ; puis avec ou sans la même ou une autre consonne de liaison avant le suffixe ? C'est à mon avis pour ça qu'on a des hésitations.

---

Avec un radical comme *combin-*, par exemple, suffixé en [-eur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ateur) on a de la difficulté à se tenir à l'écart de termes de plus en plus attestés pour des machines, techniques (*combineur, combinateur*).

---

Le suffixe [-iste](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-iste) (II.) peut être employé pour la profession ou le spécialiste même en l'absence d'un substantif en -isme correspondant pour l'activité en question (urbaniste (-isme) ; chimiste (chimie)). Le TLFi compte plus de 3000 mots avec cette finale nous dit-on... Le suffixe [-ien](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ien) (III.) peut aussi être employé pour le spécialiste, avec généralement une idée de spécialisation plus grande qu'avec le terme en -iste (TLFi) :

> Ces termes entrent, pour la plupart, dans la série suivante : le nom
>   du domaine, de la spécialité, de la science, est en *-ique* (ou
>   *-ie*); l'adjectif correspondant est en *-ique*; le nom d'agent est en *-ien*. Ainsi *l'esthétique/esthétique/esthéticien*, *la mécanique/mécanique/mécanicien*, *la
>   sémantique/sémantique/sémanticien*, *la
>   stylistique/stylistique/stylisticien*, *la
>   théologie/théologique/théologien*. On remarquera que pour les mots en
>   *-iste*, la série est différente : *-ie* (ou -*isme*)/*-ique*/*-iste*. Ainsi *chimie/chimique/chimiste*, *empirisme/empirique/empiriste*. Il
>   y a cependant des interférences entre ces deux séries. Ainsi *la
>   botanique/botanique/botaniste*, *la
>   linguistique/linguistique/linguiste*. Les noms d'agents en *-ien*
>   indiquent en général une spécialisation plus grande que les noms
>   d'agents en *-iste*. V. aussi morphologie C 2.
>  [...]
>   2. Avec le suffixe -*ique* a) *-ien* se combine volontiers à des adjectifs ou substantifs en *-ique* pour former des noms d'agents en
>   *-icien* : *acousticien, arithméticien, dialecticien, généticien, magicien, physicien, sémanticien, stoïcien, théoricien*. b) Des formes
>   en *-ien*, comme *comédien, géodésien, théologien, tragédien*, sont
>   obtenues par commutation de suffixe avec le substantif. (infra
>   étymologie et histoire B 1) et non par formation sur des adjectifs qui
>   donneraient normalement des formes en *-icien*.
>  [...]
>  Le
>   suffixe [-ien] a été très productif au XIXe siècle et il le reste au XXe
>   siècle surtout pour les dérivés formés à partir de noms de personnes
>   et pour les noms d'agents, l'apparition de sciences et de techniques
>   nouvelles lui offrant un large champ d'emploi.
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* (TLFi), entrée [*-ien*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ien), III,
>   extraits sélectionnés tirés des sections *remarques, morphologie, étymologie et histoire*, avec modifications de la présentation et des abréviations, retrait d'astérisques. ]

On aimerait bien le *combiniste* (de [*combinisme*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YYsGAAAAQAAJ&dq=combinisme&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q=combinisme&f=false), dont l'histoire dépasse le cadre de la question), qui serait peut-être celui qui élabore des *systèmes de combinaisons*. On pourrait penser au *combinaticien*. On n'a pas fini de penser aux agencements possibles... Au final la *mathématicien [discret](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math%C3%A9matiques_discr%C3%A8tes)* qu'on a déniché en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/combinatoricien-vs-combinatoriste#comment6689_3321) n'est pas mal, si ambigu selon certains...

---

**R.** La plus grande spécialisation du spécialiste avec un terme suffixé en -ien. On ne sait pas, le *combinatoriste* est presque le substantif *combinatoire* suffixé directement en -iste et il n'est pas rare d'avoir un aménagement entre la base et un suffixe. Les nuances touchent l'adéquation avec le radical des bases utilisées pour la suffixation. Mais on (je) a de la difficulté à faire cadrer un découpage du mot avec un prototype de base au lexique, le générique *mathématique* est omniprésent, la suffixation d'une composition comme *mathématiques combinatoires* pour créer un agent donnerait peut-être des résultats différents, et on (je) trouve difficile de reconnaître la *combinatoire* dans *combinatoricien* (et en anglais on (je) lit systématiquement *combinatorics* comme *combinatronics*).

Comment: Peut-être que qqn. peut faire une meilleure réponse avec ces infos. Je ne suis même pas arrivé à identifier une base étayée sur laquelle suffixer. L'information est touffue, et de toute évidence, on n'a ni l'expérience en linguistique, ni en sciences, mais bon, on essaye. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

En prenant quelque licence:

- combinatorologue
- combinatorologiste (un peu long peut-être)
- et (grand) combinateur

Comment: Je vais être direct: *avez-vous seulement lu la question?* L'invention de néologismes vaguement reliés au contexte est (aisée et) hors-sujet. Désolé.